# How can I display this json using react (get data from api)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner of coding and now I learning React also API. This case I got a problem with the data I get from API, I cannot display it, could you guys please help me how to display this data.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=X%20japan", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "genius.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "8381c61985mshd33863649f9935ap10e015jsn75abaf8b1155",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data.response.hits);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Uo</h1>
      <div>
        {data.map((item) => {
          <div>{item.hit[0]}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7QWe.jpg)

Comment: Please share some code and context. How should we be able to help you? We have no information.

Comment: Since you didn't share any code and even attached screenshot is meaningless, there's no way to figure out ***how exactly*** you want to *display this json* (e.g. stringified text? list? table?) in the first place. Furthermore, it is even unclear what *'this json'* looks like. So, consider appending more context before this question gets closed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `useEffect` return a promise. If you check the [useEffect  API docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), you can see that the function returned by a useEffect is a clean up function.
Do you see the problem here? With your code, the useEffect will always return a promise and not a function.

To execute async code in a useEffect, you have to create a scoped async function and execute it in the useEffect like the example below:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('...');
      const data = await res.json();

      setData(data);
   }

  fetchData();
}, []);


return (
     <div>
        {data.map(item => (
           <div>{item.hit[0]}</div>
        ))}
     </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://genius.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=X%20japan", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "genius.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "8381c61985mshd33863649f9935ap10e015jsn75abaf8b1155",
      },
    })
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.response.hits);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Uo</h1>
        {data && data.map(item => <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(item, null, 2)}
        </pre>)}
    </div>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 0):

The schema of the JSON received from your request can be explained using TypeScript as follow:

```
interface Hit {
  highlights: Array<string>
  index: string
  type: string
  result: Object
  title: string
  title_with_featured: string
  url: string
  primary_artist: Object
}

interface Response {
  meta: {
    status: number
  }
  response: { 
    hits: Array<Hit>
  }
}
```

In these lines of your code,

```
{/* ... */}
<div>
   {data.map(item => (
      <div>{item.hit[0]}</div>
   ))}
</div>
{/* ... */}
```

you're trying to print out an object (of type `Hit` to be exact) out inside `<div>` tag, which is not possible. Only string and array of strings are allowed to be printed out inside of `<div>`

For example, this code snippet below will work:

```
{/* ... */}
<div>
   {data.map(function (hit) {
      return (
        <div>{`Song title: ${hit.title}`}</div>
        <div>{`Performer: ${hit.primary_artist.name}`}</div>
      )}
   }
</div>
{/* ... */}
```

Another hack is to convert the whole responsed data object into string using `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
<div>
   {data.map(function (hit) {
      return (
        <div>{`Data: ${JSON.stringify(hit)}`}</div>
      )}
   }
</div>
```